# How to use Laravael 5.2 custom pagination?

Tags: pagination, laravel-5

I am trying to make a custom pagination, feeded with data from an array. I use an array/object and not result from query, becouse I can't get the data only from the query,the data is calculated with other funtions and inserted in array.

This is how array looks like(can also be an object):

```
 0 => array:7 [▼
    "name" => "Arnold"
    "group_id" => "1004"
    "trans_number" => "38"
    "totalCommissions" => "669.25"
    "paidTransactions" => 675
    "reversedTransactions" => 362
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "name" => "Nixon"
    "group_id" => "1038"
    "trans_number" => "787"
    "totalCommissions" => "925.25"
    "paidTransactions" => 1340
    "reversedTransactions" => 906
  ]
  2 => array:7 [▼
    "name" => "Rhoe, Brittany"
    "group_id" => "1049"
    "trans_number" => "720"
    "totalCommissions" => "963.75"
    "paidTransactions" => 1695
    "reversedTransactions" => 1147
  ]
  3 => array:7 [▼
    "name" => "Perez"
    "group_id" => "1026"
    "trans_number" => "1147"
    "totalCommissions" => "1,459.75"
    "paidTransactions" => 2398
    "reversedTransactions" => 1527
  ]
```

The idea is: how to use Laravel 5.2 Pagination class, to render that data in blade view? most of the examples on web looks to be abit outdated....or I can't figure out how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation for the Paginator here:

- [Paginator Doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html#method___construct)
- [LengthAwarePaginator Doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html#method___construct)

A simple example, using Paginator:

in controller:

```
$paginator = new \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator($array, $perPage, $currPage);
```

in view:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($paginator as $person)
        {{ $person->name }}
        {{ $person->group_id }}
        {{ $person->trans_number }}
        {{ $person->totalCommissions }}
        {{ $person->paidTransactions }}
        {{ $person->reversedTransactions }}
    @endforeach
</div>

// render pagination buttons
{!! $paginator->links() !!}
```

Comment: josevh, where did you generate your avatar?

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir.